# How to avoid oversized factory contracts in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have a large contract which I managed to reduce in size to just under the size limit using libraries, etc. and it is now about 21K.  Now I want to make a on-chain factory for this large contract

The problem is even though the factory contract contains nothing but a "makeFoo()" function, and a constructor the factory contract size is over 25K and can't be deployed.

All that's in the factory contract is something like this:

```
contract FooFactory {
    address private _adminAddress;
 
    function makeFoo(string memory name, string memory symbol) public returns(address) {
        Foo newFoo = new Foo(name, symbol, msg.sender, _adminAddress);
        return address(newFoo);
    }

    constructor(address adminAddress_) {
        _adminAddress = adminAddress_;
    }    
}
```

Is there any other way besides "new" to "clone" a contract that's already deployed to the blockchain that doesn't result in the size of the factory contract to be 115% of the size of any contract upon which it calls "new"?

Comment: `> Is there any other way besides "new" to "clone" a contract that's already deployed to the blockchain that doesn't result in the size of the factory contract to be 115% of the size of any contract upon which it calls "new"?` There is not AFAIK - the only way to avoid situations like this is to design smart contracts smart.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, we are bound by the size limit. There have been discussions to remove it, but those have died down over the years.

You can take the following steps to work-around the size limitation:

- Split contracts into smaller, functionally grouped contracts. (HIGH IMPACT). Similar functions are put into a single contract. You can have sets of such contracts.
- Split storage and functionality contracts.
- Separate and refactor logic code into libraries.  (HIGH IMPACT)
- Use smaller types for struct fields  (MED IMPACT)
- Bundled getters that return many values at once. Instead of having a getter for individual variables.  (MED IMPACT)
- Avoid additional variables. In functions, directly fetch a value instead of first storing it in a variable. (MED IMPACT)
- Use functions instead of modifiers. Modifiers have a heavy impact on code size when used a lot. This is because the entire function body is copied over into the modifier at compile time, thereby increasing contract size. (HIGH IMPACT)